# Python genetic algorithm is slow

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I made a genetic algorithm that writes the target phrase, but i'm feeling that it takes too long on each iteration, so I'd like to know if you have any idea on how to speed it up.

Thanks

```
from random import randint, random
from time import time

def rescale(X,A,B,C,D,force_float=False):
    retval = ((float(X - A) / (B - A)) * (D - C)) + C
    if not force_float and all(map(lambda x: type(x) == int, [X,A,B,C,D])):
        return int(round(retval))
    return retval
```

Here i create a list of random characters that form the phrase

```
class DNA:
    def __init__(self,num):
        self.genes=[]
        for i in range(num):
            self.genes.append((chr(randint(32,126))))
```

Transform the genes in a string

```
    def getPhrase(self):
        return(''.join(self.genes))
```

Calculating the fitness(similarity to the target)

```
    def fitness(self,target):
        score=0
        for i in range(len(self.genes)):
            if (self.genes[i] == target[i]): 
                score+=1

        return score*score/(len(target)*len(target))
```

Mixing two genes (getting some character from one and some from another)

```
    def crossover(self,partner):

        child = DNA(len(self.genes))

        midpoint = randint(0,len(self.genes))

        for i in range(len(self.genes)): 
            if (i > midpoint):
                child.genes[i] = self.genes[i]
            else:              
                child.genes[i] = partner.genes[i]
        return child
```

Mutating a gene(adding some random characters)

```
    def mutate(self,mutationRate):
        for i in range(len(self.genes)):
            if (random() < mutationRate):
                self.genes[i] = chr(randint(32,126))
```

A list of DNA objects

```
class Population:

    def __init__(self,target,mutationRate,num):
        self.population=[]
        for i in range(num): 
            self.population.append(DNA(len(target)))

        self.mutationRate=mutationRate
        self.calcFitness(target)
        self.generations=0
```

Making a list with the fitness of each gene

```
    def calcFitness(self,target):
        self.fitness=[]
        for i in range(len(self.population)):
            self.fitness.append(self.population[i].fitness(target))
```

Making a list to the crossover function, with entries proportional to the fitness

```
    def naturalSelection(self):
        global index, x
        self.matingPool=[]

        self.maxFitness = 0
        for i in range(len(self.population)):
            if (self.fitness[i] > self.maxFitness):
                self.maxFitness = self.fitness[i]
                index=i

        print(DNA.getPhrase(population.population[index]),'            generation: ',self.generations)
        if (DNA.getPhrase(population.population[index]))==target:
            x=False
        for i in range(len(self.population)):
            fitness = rescale(self.fitness[i],0,float(self.maxFitness),0,1)
            n = (fitness * 100)
            for j in range(int(n)):
                self.matingPool.append(population.population[i])
```

Updating the population

```
    def generate(self):
        for i in range(len(self.population)):
            a = randint(0,len(self.matingPool)-1)
            b = randint(0,len(self.matingPool)-1)
            partnerA = self.matingPool[a]
            partnerB = self.matingPool[b]
            child = partnerA.crossover(partnerB)
            child.mutate(self.mutationRate)
            population.population[i] = child
        self.generations+=1

start=time()
target= input("Target:  ")        
population = Population(target, 0.05,300)
x=True
while x==True:
    population.naturalSelection()
    population.generate()
    population.calcFitness(target)
end=time()
print(end-start)
```

Comment: If the code is complete, and works, and you just want improvement suggestions, it should be on Code Review, not here.

Comment: As a general rule, if you want to optimize code, then use a `profiler` to figure out what the slow part is. Then work to avoid that or speed it up.

Comment: This code is not complete, the `index` global variable is not defined and we don't know what to give it when it asks for input.

Comment: You may consider posting a [mcve].

Comment: Lot of loops here. You should avoid them and vectorize your code. Or switch to C/++.